# Fact Table Construction on Multiple Dimensions on Membership

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, data-warehouse

We are building a data warehouse and having an issue with construction of a fact table. Our company enrolls members on various levels of membership, promotions, and rates. We would like to create a fact table that could display all current membership information with the ability to roll out old information or changes to the membership. The tables we are using are as follows…

(Member Status | Start Date |End Date)

(Member Privilege | Price | Cycle | Start Date | End Date)

(Member Promotion | Associated Discount | Start Date | End Date)

(Member Type | Start Date | End Date)

(Personal Information | Address | Phone | Ect)

We would like the fact table to display all this information based upon Personal Id. (Personal information needs to remain a dimensional table without many to many relationships due to this information is used in other fact tables.) The issue is that we could have multiple privileges or promotions attached to one member. Is it better to have these be independent fact tables or what is the best way to get this information into one table?

Comment: it would depend on the amount of data and the speed needed (for reporting etc).  In many cases creating summary tables or indexed views can alleviate some of the performance issues.  Normalization rules should be used, but in many cases don't try to normalize too much, because too many tables causes a huge number of joins needed to create queries and could make development harder and performance worse.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, It is a significant amount of data and the only static  table is status. We could add more promotions or privileges at any point in time. Were trying to hold true to a traditional star schema but this my not be a good idea.